# how to collect info from Mui date picker

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datepicker, onchange

I have a date picker from MUI and I would like to collect start and end date the same way we collect date from input fields. Here is my code:

```
const Dates = [
  { label: "From", name:"From" ,placeholder: "Start Date" },
  { label: "To", name:"To" ,placeholder: "End Date" },
];

const [value, setValue] = useState({new Date()});

  const handleChange = (name,newValue) => {
    setValue({name:newValue});
  };
<div className="dates">
            {Dates.map((date, i) => {
              return (
                <div className="formInput" key={i}>
                  <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
                    <DesktopDatePicker
                      label={date.label}
                      inputFormat="MM/dd/yyyy"
                      value={value}
                      name={date.name}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                      renderInput={(params) => (
                        <TextField placeholder={date.placeholder} {...params} />
                      )}
                    />
                  </LocalizationProvider>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
```

here is how i would like to collect the date data

```
setData((prev) => ({ ...prev, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }));
```

is this possible for the date picker if not, how do i go about it?

Comment: You have `setValue`, `setData`. A default value of `{new Date()}` and you are trying to update to `{name:newValue}`. And then: *here is how i would like to collect the date data* which seems completely unrelated to your snippet. I'm confused.

Comment: That is how I normally collect data from a normal  input filed in react ,I want to collect the dates the same way Iis it possible if not how would you recommend i do it?

Comment: I think you are missing the point. You code example is broken. It doesn't make any sense. If I am to make sense of your question I have to make assumptions about what you want your code to actually look like. If you force people to make assuptions about what you want, different people will make different assumtions. Your question will get bad quality answers, etc. Correct your code example. Make it non-ambiguous. Was that clear enough?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your `handleChange` function accordingly to achieve that:

```
const Dates = [
  { label: "From", name: "From", placeholder: "Start Date" },
  { label: "To", name: "To", placeholder: "End Date" },
];

const Test = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState({});

  const handleChange = (name, newValue) => {
    setValue((prev) => ({ ...prev, [name]: newValue }));
  };

  <div className="dates">
    {Dates.map((date, i) => {
      return (
        <div className="formInput" key={i}>
          <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
            <DesktopDatePicker
              label={date.label}
              inputFormat="MM/dd/yyyy"
              value={value}
              name={date.name}
              onChange={handleChange}
              renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField placeholder={date.placeholder} {...params} />
              )}
            />
          </LocalizationProvider>
        </div>
      );
    })}
  </div>;
};

export default Test;
```